# Can I override strapi api?

Tags: strapi

recently i've discovered this fantastic headless cms **strapi**, and i'd like to use it in my next project.

But i have a big question. Are the api overridable? Especially the controllers.
I cannot find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible without changing the strapi's own controllers. But by doing so, you may have headaches in the future when you need to upgrade the strapi version.

Depending on your need, [policies](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/policies.html), [middlewares](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/advanced/middlewares.html) and [hooks](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/advanced/hooks.html) can help you a lot.

Comment: We are doing an active work on the `override` subject. It will be release in the next month.

Answer (score 0):

There is no logic that will be updated in controllers. So you can easily customise your controller without having problem for the update (instead of what @capaci said) All the logic is in the services.

So today you can `customise` all the code of your API but not `override`.

We are currently working to split `core` vs `custom` code to be able to add this `override` notion in Strapi.